# best practice for organizing your class/subclass files

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, organization, code-organization

This is more of a preference question but I want to know what do people prefer when organizing their application's directory tree for managing classes, and subclasses.

given the file name = class name

## A - subclassing within folders

`Foo.php`

`Foo/Bar.php` // extends `Foo`

`Foo/Bar/Baz.php` // extends `Foo\Bar`

#### Real World Example

`Post.php`

`Post/Media.php` - extends `Post`

`Post/Media/Image.php` - extends `Post\Media`

`Post/Media/Audio.php` - extends `Post\Media`

## B - subclassing within the class name

`Foo.php`

`BarFoo.php`

`BazBarFoo.php`

#### Real World Example

`Post.php`

`MediaPost.php` - extends `Post`

`ImageMediaPost.php` - extends `MediaPost`

`AudioMediaPost.php` - extends `MediaPost`

---

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, subclassing is an anti-pattern. It tightly couples classes together, and can result in some hard-to-maintain code. It's much more appropriate to have clean interfaces with inversion of control. You'll then end up with small components that do one job, and one only. I'm going to answer your question though, but I needed to tell you why I think this:

If you use subclassing a lot, that alone creates huge coupling. Representing that coupling in the filesystem too is another layer, which will make it very hard to later on modify your code.
Namespacing and packaging based on the responsibilities of the classes/interfaces has proven to be the best way for me.

This is a good piece of writing about how to think of responsibilities: http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html

Comment: Thanks for the added knowledge but subclassing would still be required in some cases. Suppose I have the generic Media class that implements an interface. I would still need the methods implemented as so my Image and Video subclass can inherit the methods already implemented. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yep, indeed! :)
You can have your Media class that has the interface a generic Media has to have.
To make multiple "types" of media, you can use the Decorator pattern for example. It's outlined here for php: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator/php

Basically your Image and Video would both implement the same interface the Media does, but would delegate those methods to the main class's instance they've received as they were constructed.

It's best explained in code :) https://gist.github.com/meza/1702a294825996aa35d6

Comment: Thank you for the gist and the reference to the Decorator pattern.